# Publishing messages from Twisted Client to ZeroMQ

Tags: python, twisted, zeromq

In my Twisted application , i want to publish messages to the ZeroMQ message queue.
Can i do something like below in the Protocol class ?

```
from twisted.internet import protocol,reactor
import zmq

class MyClient(protocol.Protocol):
  def __init__(self):
    self.context = zmq.Context()
    self.socket =  context.socket(zmq.PUB)
    self.socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5000")

  def dataReceived(self,data):
     #Do something with the data to get a result
     #...
     #Publish to 0mq
     self.socket.send(result)

#Code below for factory and initializing reactor
#...

reactor.run()
```

Would the above work, if not why ?. If it wont work then should I use txZMQ (https://github.com/smira/txZMQ) ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you actually tried it yet? What happened?

Comment: @Jason: Trying it is not going to help! It will appear to work, but this is misleading as the `send` call is blocking.

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour of the [`Socket.send`](https://zeromq.github.io/pyzmq/api/zmq.html#zmq.Socket.send) method is to block until the message has been queued on the socket. If the socket queue is full, then nothing else will happen in your Twisted application until there is room on the socket to queue the message.

The `NOBLOCK` flag to the `send` method tells `zmq` to raise an exception if it can't queue the message. But if you do this, then you have to worry about failures:

```
try:
    self.socket.send(result, flags=zmq.NOBLOCK)
except zmq.Again:
    # Failed to queue the message: what now?
```

It would simpler to use the [txZMQ](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/txZMQ/) package, which integrates ZMQ with the Twisted event loop. The [examples](http://txzmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html#publish-subscribe) in the [documentation](http://txzmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) suggest that you implement publishing in txZMQ like this:

```
factory = ZmqFactory()
publisher = ZmqPubConnection(factory, endpoint)
publisher.publish(message)
```

Comment: itris running the code in official docs but ther is no ouput just the blank screen